# Save file dialog box, when creating excel file in java using extjs

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4.1 and spring mvc 3. I am passing some values from extjs form to the spring controller and then int java side I am creating an excel sheet with the data that I get from DB.
My problem is that I am not able to get the save file dialog box when the excel gets created. I have written this piece of code also

```
String filename="tradeReport.xlsx";
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

Excel sheet creating code:

```
try {
    OutputStream outs=res.getOutputStream();
    //FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/data/tradereport.xls"));
    workbook.write(outs);
    //outs.flush();
    outs.close();
    System.out.println("File created!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This function I am writting in DAO class.

Note:-Excel is being created successfully when using

`FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/data/tradereport.xls"));`

Please help me with a solution.Thanks

Comment: Can any one please help me with this issue

Comment: Try to set the content type: `res.setContentType("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");`

Comment: Darin, as u can see I am already setting the content-type in the header,

Comment: My problem is that,in the extjs side I dont know what to do,as I am sending back the response from Spring controller.
My extjs code is :-                                              
 var tmpSummaryTabFilterDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
model: 'FXDAC.model.SummaryListModel',proxy{ type: 'ajax', api: { read: tmpSummaryExcelUrl }, timeout : 240000, 
             reader: {
                  type: 'json',
                  root: 'Summary List Excel',
                  successProperty: 'success'
              }
          }
      });
      tmpSummaryTabFilterDataStore.load();

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the browser prompt the user to save the file without loosing the current window, I've found the trick of opening a hidden iframe with the download url works well.

```
    var uri = 'http://www.com.test/my/download/url';
    Ext.DomHelper.append(Ext.getBody(), {
        tag: 'iframe',
        id: 'iframe-export',
        frameBorder: 0,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        css: 'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',
        src: uri
    });
```

It requires the Content-Disposition and Content-Type headers to be set as you are already doing.